# resending peerconnection offer

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, webrtc

I'm currently trying to rebroadcast my local stream to all my peer connections. options I tried:

1) Loop trough all my peer connection and recreate them with the new local stream. Problem that I encounter here is the fact that createOffer is asynchronous.

2) create 1 sdp and send it to all peers. Problem: no video

Would anyone have a way to resend an offer to a list of peers?

Comment: You can use the same mediaStream across all your connections but each connection needs their own SDP(this is because of ICE candidates chosen in the connection). Are you also handling the renegotiation on the other side?

Comment: the offer is handled correctly on the receiving end. (receiving side recreates its peer connection with the new stream) so is the answer. the problem is indeed that I need a new SDP for each peer connection. SO what would probably fix my problem is if I was able to call createOffer() in a loop. however due to this being async all the sdp's get send to the last connection in the list.

Comment: You COULD wait for each createOffer to finish and once it finishes it calls the next connection to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Each PC needs to recreate an offer (as bwrent said).
- as you obviously are using a p2p multiparty (multiple peer connections) you might want to pass on the peerID to the createOffer success callback every time, then you don't have to worry about it being asynchronous. You need to make the full handshake (offer, answer, candidate) peerID dependent.
- (Simplified) Example from our SDK

```
    Skyway.prototype._doCall = function (targetMid) {
        var pc = this._peerConnections[targetMid]; // this is thread / asynchronous safe
        pc.createOffer(
            function (offer) {
                self._setLocalAndSendMessage(targetMid, offer); // pass the targetID down the callback chain
            },
            function (error) {this._onOfferOrAnswerError(targetMid, error);},
            constraints
        );
    }; 

    Skyway.prototype._setLocalAndSendMessage = function (targetMid, sessionDescription) {
        var pc = this._peerConnections[targetMid]; // this is thread / asynchronous safe
        pc.setLocalDescription(
            sessionDescription,
            self._sendMessage({ target: targetMid, ... }), // success callback
            function () {}                                 // error   callback
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean async in a way that when a callback fires it has the wrong variable of who to send it to as the loop has ended and the variable contains the last 'person'? You could scope it to solve the asynchronous problem:

```
For(var i=0;i<peerConnections.length;i++){
    (function(id){
        //inside here you have the right id. Even if the loop ended and the i variable has changed to something else, the I'd variable still is the same.
    })(i);
}
```

This is a bit like Alex' answer, as his anwer also describes an example of scoping the variable inside the function executing the .createOffer

Another way to handle this correctly is to use renegotiation. Whenever you change a stream, the on onnegotiation event handler is automatically fired. Inside this function you create a new offer and send that to the other person. As you mentioned you have multiple peer connect ions listening to the stream, you need to know whom to send the sdp to. If you would add the persons id to the rtc object, you can then get it back inside the onnegotioation event by calling `this.id`.

Comment: I currently went for the solution Alex proposed. However I will have a look into onrenegotiation at a later point. This might be a better solution in the long run. thanks for the tip.

Comment: @user3428043 It is indeed something a 'well-developed' rtc system uses. This automatically handles resending SDP's whenever a stream changes, without you having to think about handling SDP's whenever you change a stream. I am not quite sure but maybe it also triggers when something else changes (and prevents a connection from failing). However when using this you should add the event handler after you have successfully established a connection, else you might get double SDP's.

Comment: renegociation and rollback are indeed the right way to do this. It should be hidden form the app. Good webRTC sdk out there implement it for you as unfortunately, even though the specs define the onrenegotiationneeded event, FF does not implement it, and the rollback part is not yet in the spec and will likely not make it to 1.0. cheers.